# How to open few urls from database in new tabs with a single click

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I found the answer how to open few pages in new tabs with a single click, but I don't know how to place urls from mysqli database using fetch.

mysqli statement is ...

```
$pick_site = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT url FROM sites where chosen = ? ORDER BY name ASC");
$pick_site->bind_param('s', $yesterday);   
$pick_site->execute(); 
$pick_site->store_result();
$pick_site->bind_result($list_sites);

while ($pick_site->fetch_array()) {
    $mysites = $list_sites;
    }
```

here is working javascript code for opening tabs

```
<a id="test" href="#"> CLick </a>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
   window.open("http://www.google.com",'_blank');
   window.open("http://www.p3php.in",'_blank');
}
</script>
```

Thank you very much,
Ivan.

Comment: If you know how to open one URL in a new tab, wouldn't it be easy to do the same with multiple URL's, and maybe you should add the code for a single URL here ?

Comment: sorry I just clicked enter before I placed the code

Comment: So are you trying to get those with ajax after pageload, or just to echo them out in a javascript variable so you can use them later.

Comment: I just want to echo them and use when I click the button. There will be also single links on the page, but this will speed up things by clicking only one button. Each day there will be different sites so it is important to read all urls from database.

Answer (score 1):

Just echo links like that :

```
<a id="test" href="#"> CLick </a>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){

    <?php while ($pick_site->fetch_array()) { ?>    
     window.open("<?= $link ?>",'_blank');
    <?php } ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: Great, it works! Just needed to replace "$link" with "$list_sites" Thank you very much.

Comment: And mysqli "fetch_array" with "fetch", but this is my mistake. :)

Comment: Yes, it works with those replacement. Here is a working code... <?php while ($pick_site->fetch()) { ?>  
         window.open("<?= $list_sites ?>",'_blank');
    <?php } ?>